# Thread safety with atomic operations in multi core environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I heard that a single atomic operation is thread-safe because when a core is processing an atomic operation the core wouldn't be doing anything else before it completes that atomic operation .

for example in java in a 32 bit operating system say there is a variable accessible to multiple Threads

```
 int a;
```

thread 1 write in a

```
a = 3;
```

and thread 2 can write

```
a = 4;
```

the order of the threads writing to that variable may change so the final value can either be 3 or 4 but we can be sure that writing to an int is an atomic operation so the 32 bits in that variable won't be mixed up in to some unpredictable number

I get that this is the case in a single core environment since the core would not be executing a code of another thread before it is sure that the atomic operation is complete,

however in a multi core environment isn't it possible that another core accesses the variable that is under an atomic operation of the current core?  thus causing the 32bits in the variable to get mixed up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - that's what atomic means: the write will always succeed "without interference". So you will either read 0 (the original value), 3 or 4 but no other value.

What will happen in a multi core setting is that if thread T1 writes 3 on core C1 and thread T2 writes 4 on core C2, the value may remain visible only to the core that made the write. So your `int` may have a value of 3 in C1 and 4 in C2 *at the same time*. And if there is a third core C3, it may still see the original value of 0.

To prevent that inconsistency, you need to add some synchronization (for example by making the int volatile).

Comment: Or you simply use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). It is specially designed for multi-threaded use and therefore sychronized by design.

Answer (score 1):

In short, none of example operations are thread safe. You need to use atomics or synchronization to grantee any predictable output. In the given example it is even possible that on reading thread 'a' will endup as 0 and will nether be updated to '3' or '4'.

Atomics are not just about atomicity, they are also about ordering. And the latter is the cornerstone of all concurrent programming.

Keep in mind that there are many things, which can go wrong and it is not only what is going on in the CPU. Compiler also reorder operations or even eliminate main memory writes.

I would recommend reading the following links to understand how all that stuff works:

- Doug Lea page for compiler writers: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html
- Alexey Shipilev on JMM: http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/ and http://shipilev.net in general.
- Very interesting example by Bartosz Milewski of what can break when things are not properly synchronized: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/

Comment: Re, "none of example operations are thread safe."  That depends on what "thread safe" means.  In the OP's example, any thread that tries to read `a` is guaranteed to get either 0, or 3, or 4.  Depending on what role `a` plays in the application, that may _be_ thread safe.  If it's not, then most likely "thread safe" implies a relationship between `a` and _other variables_ that have not been shown in the example.

Comment: yes what  i meant by being thread safe is what james has described, I do know that the order will be unpredictable and since the variable is not volatile it may not be correctly updated for different threads, anyway thank you very much for both of you

Comment: @jameslarge what I mean is even when both writer thread complete, there is not guarantee that reader thread will see 3 or 4. If that is what expected by program, then yes, it's thread-safe :)

Comment: To make the OP's example more concrete, picture three threads waiting at a barrier.  When the barrier is lifted, one sets `a=3`, one sets `a=4`, and one does `println(a)`.  Output will be unpredictable:  0, or 3, or 4, Right?  Now picture, the threads using a `synchronized` getter and setter instead of directly accessing `a`.  Does it help?  No!  Output still could be 0, or 3, or 4.  It's not the _operations_ that are "unsafe" here:  No amount of synchronization can make them any safer than they already are.  What's "unsafe" (i.e., unpredictable) is the _whole example._